# Display non-linear data structure like tree in Android View

Tags: java, android, data-structures

I want to integrate a tree view in my application with data structure like below image.

My application data is dynamic which comes from SQLite database.

[image]

Any idea how can I achieve this?

Comment: Check out this : https://code.google.com/p/tree-view-list-android/

Comment: Haresh Chhelana : but i want graphical view as per my above image,  this is listview type structure

Comment: do you want to acces the data structure (like: add onClickListener on Uruguay) or do you simply want to display the graph?